# A gem for saving report filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filtering

I'm building a new website where users can create their own reports.
The report consists of blocks and a block can be a graph or a table. So such a block visualizes some data. The user can chose which objects are the source of that block and the filters on that. From an existing block he can edit those filters. reports are saved so later on such a report can be called and the data in the graphs and tables is updates.

Are there any gems or methods in Ruby On Rails how I can achieve the saving of such data filtering?

One way could be generating SQL code when creating a block, but I have to save a lot of information then to be able to edit such a block.

Thanks
Laurens

Comment: [report](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/report) ≠ [rapport](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rapport)

Comment: Thanks Jordan, I changed it. It's called Rapport in dutch..

Answer (score 1):

You could store report filters in nosql database such as mongodb. With this solution it will be very easy to store and retrieve those params as JSON documents.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @luacassus. But could you explain it some more? I have investigated Mongodb a bit and saw some advantages (less work when adding and removing attributes and sometimes speed advantages) but not how it could help in this case? As I understand, I still have to create Ruby objects with all the possible properties.. create savings objects.. etc.. I see no difference in the pure Ruby On Rails code?